# confused about which graphics driver is loaded

Tags: ati

Using Ubuntu 12.10, and I have 2 graphics card, Intel and ATI, and I finally get proprietary ATI driver to work -version 13.1-, but when I check `lshw` and `lsmod`, I get confused.

Here's the output of lshw -the confusing part is the driver property-:

```
*-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: Cape Verde [Radeon HD 7700M Series]
                ...
                configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
                ...

*-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
             ...
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             ...
```

and Here's lsmod output:

```
lsmod | grep radeon > returns nothing after I installed the ATI driver

lsmod | grep fglrx
fglrx                5196783  116

lsmod | grep video
video                  19335  1 i915
```

I expected the video value to be `fglrx_pci` or `fglrx` not `i915`,
am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lshw` shows you the hardware that is installed in your PC. Two times display is ok, when you have two graphiccards.

`lsmod` shows you the loaded modules. You have two graphiccards, so I think it is no problem that the modules for both are loaded.

Both commands doesen't show you which driver is loaded or used.

EDIT: You can try this: `glxinfo | grep render`

Comment: `glxinfo` didn't work, instead I found `fglrxinfo`. thanks for the information.